# OO design: should collections always be stored?

Tags: collections, uml

I've wondered this in many different situations, so here I come, looking for the experts knowledge.
Let's say I have to model something that requires a collection. A simple example: an application that stores famous quotes along with their author and a set of tags or keywords. The user should be able to enter a tag or keyword and get matching quotes for it.
My question is: do I really need a class that contains my collection of quotes? Something like this:
[image: example 1]

Or would this also be correct?

[image: example 2]

I'm asking this in the more abstract way possible (after all, UML should never depend on the implementation).
I've always thought the second example (just 1 class) was incorrect, but now I'm thinking that maybe the user can press a button on some interface and that button executes some code that gets a quote stored somewhere, and the second example would also be correct?

Basically, should I always have a collection stored somewhere, even if the storing class does nothing else but just store the collection (and provide the methods to access it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitelly prefer only one class, if there is no strong reason to have another container class (especially on abstract conceptual level). Then I add the collection methods as **static functions**. A separate container class would only bring more complexity, more dependencies and doubts like yours. :) Doubts often indicate the lack of a real need. When you really need something, you know it.

Here an example with some explanations. I find it simple, clear, elegant and abstract, meaning non-restrictive, easy to transform to any implementation you like:

[image]

When it comes to relationships of this class to other class, then you actially have your collection, without introducing new class. This diagram shows two examples. "Other class" actually sees a collection "quotes" which is ordered, like Vector. "One more class" also has a collection of Quotes with different characteristics.

Later on implementation level you can implement it directly like this or eventually adding a Factory or Container class, according to concrete, implemention resctrictions and special reqs.

Comment: I had never thought of the static methods solution! Pretty cool and simple. Thanks!

Comment: One more comment: in this case I would definitely need a static attribute to store my collection, right? Otherwise there's no way to store the return value from the create() method (this method creates the collection, if I didn't get it wrong).

Comment: No, no static attributes at all, at least not for that purpose. Static create() simply creates a fresh instance of a new Quote and returns it to a caller, whichever caller it is! It's normally some other class.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this :P
If there's no static attribute where you store the collection, then you DO need another class to store it, right? If this was the whole application (no other classes) then it would need that static collection attribute? Otherwise I don't see where the collection of "Quote" objects would be stored when you want to access it. Sorry, I'm a bit confused!

Comment: If you have an underlaying DB or any other external storage, that the "collection" is practically in the DB and you can always retrieve the objects by a simple SQL query or similar (implemented in a static methods, as told). If your objects live in the memory (no DB), than you need a private static data member to keep the references to all instances of the given class.